# How to stop SQLServer writing extraneous stuff eg (1 rows affected)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a command I can run inside my SQL script so that it stops outputing information about each operation that gets run?

ie I don't want to see this:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

to suppress these messages and use the command below to enable the messages.

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Answer (score 22):

run this command:

```
set nocount on
```

Comment: ...everywhere! stored procs, triggers. the lot