# When I run simple select query, is it possible not to show number of rows affected at the end?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I try to use OSQL in order to save query results in text file and later bulk insert those text file to a table. OSQL part is ok, however, in bulk insert, number of rows affected at the end of query results causes error. Here is an example;

```
select item_number, description, price from item

3536114   Fruit mix     $3.99

3536229   DO 20 liquid  $9.99

3536251   Peppermint    $7.99

(3 rows affected) ------> I do not need this line.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377067/how-to-stop-sqlserver-writing-extraneous-stuff-eg-1-rows-affected

Answer (score 6):

Use [`SET NOCOUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259204%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) like so:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

This will:

> Stops the message indicating the number of rows affected by a
>   Transact-SQL statement from being returned as part of the results.

Answer (score 3):

Put this at the top of the query:

`SET NOCOUNT ON`

> When SET NOCOUNT is ON, the count is not returned. When SET NOCOUNT is
>   OFF, the count is returned.
>
> The @@ROWCOUNT function is updated even when SET NOCOUNT is ON.
>
> SET NOCOUNT ON prevents the sending of DONE_IN_PROC messages to the
>   client for each statement in a stored procedure. For stored procedures
>   that contain several statements that do not return much actual data,
>   or for procedures that contain Transact-SQL loops, setting SET NOCOUNT
>   to ON can provide a significant performance boost, because network
>   traffic is greatly reduced.
>
> The setting specified by SET NOCOUNT is in effect at execute or run
>   time and not at parse time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can achive this by:-

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON
```

When SET NOCOUNT is ON, the count (indicating the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement) is not returned. When SET NOCOUNT is OFF, the count is returned.

Check this [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259204%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)